# How to fetch results in an array with ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am trying to get some distinct values from DB with ZF2 using Tablegateway.

```
    $select = $this->sql->select($tableGateway->getTable());

    $select->columns(array('city'));
    $select->quantifier('DISTINCT');

    $stm = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
    $res = $stm->execute();
    return $res;
```

This is returning an Iterate object, and I would like to have all the cities in an array. How can I do this ?

Comment: If you are getting **Zend\Db\ResultSet** then just do `$res->toArray();`.

Comment: I am having this error :  Call to undefined method Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Result::toArray()

Comment: How can I get Zend\Db\ResultSet instead ?

Comment: ok I managed to use ResultSet and I can use toArray. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the url if anyone need it : http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.db.result-set.html

Answer (score 1):

```
// whatever $select

$stm = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
$res = $stm->execute();

$resultSet = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
$resultSet->initialize($res);

foreach ($resultSet->toArray() as $row) {
    // ...
}
```